# Discord.js を使ったグローバルチャット内での処罰システム

Tags: javascript, discord

私はDiscord.jsを使ってグローバルチャットを作っています。
[この方](https://qiita.com/Yopon/items/05b65f445a48d3759c50) のサイトを参考に作っていました。
そこでこれMute出来ないと荒らされるのでは？と思い質問しました。
コマンドを検知するところはわかるのですか、Mute・Banする機構がわからないです。
グローバルチャットで発言した時、すべてのサーバーに適応されずに発言したメッセージを削除するようにしたいです。
**発言** -> **BOTが検知** -> **メッセージを削除** -> 導入しているサーバー全てにメッセージが行かないようにしたいです。
回答お願いします。

Answer (score 3):

私はブラックリストのフィルターをこのようにしています。
elseの部分はreturn;でも代用できるかと思います。

```
const blacklist = ["ここにミュートする人のID"]

if (blacklist.includs(message.author.id)){
    message.delete()
}else{
    //処理
}
```

Answer (score 0):

特定のユーザーの発言が他サーバーに広がらないように設定するのが誰なのか、をちゃんと設計せねばなりませんが、ユーザーの ID が取れているのであれば bot 側でメッセージを送る前にフィルターすれば良いです。ユーザー ID のブラックリストを bot 側で持っておいて、メッセージごとにチェックを入れる形です。

Comment: 回答、ありがとうございます。ブラックリストをチェックする機構がわかりません。