# discord.js global ban

Tags: discord

私は、今Discord のbotを作っているのですが、グローバルBanをする方法がわかりません。
*discord.js

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [How to ban someone that's not in the server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63621712/9014308), [Using Discord.js, is there a way to ban a user who is not in the current guild? \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64515860/9014308), [Discord.js v12 Ban Command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64315562/9014308), [Discord.js を使ったグローバルチャット内での処罰システム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66910/26370), [“discord.js v12 command ban” Code Answer](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/discord.js+v12+command+ban)

Comment: どのような行為を指して「グローバルBan」と呼んでらっしゃいますでしょうか？